# Gem5 full system emulation (x86) - booting linux is very slow

Tags: linux, x86, qemu, boot, gem5

I am trying to boot linux with gem5. I am new to gem5 and so facing few problems. I am using AtomicSimpleCPU and I have compiled the linux kernel version 4.17 and created disk image with qemu.
This booting up takes very long approximately 30 to 40 minutes. I just want to know if it really takes 30 minutes to boot linux with AtomicSimpleCPU. If so, is there any other way of reducing this time.
Thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: I have given some reference numbers for ARM at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47997565/gem5-system-requirements-for-decent-performance/48941793#48941793 which might help extrapolate, see also further tests on reference link there. Would be good to clarify if boot to start of init, or boot to getting a shell (after all init initialization is finished), boot to shell on Ubuntu could be much slower than boot to shell on a more minimal distribution like Buildroot for example.

Comment: I am concerned about boot to shell. @CiroSantilli
I referred to your github repo, which was mentioned in your previous answer and it was much helpful. Thank you.